# PHP: explode but ignore escaped delimiter

Tags: php

I have a flatfile database and it is data seperated by delimiters.

I allow people to use the delimiter in their input but I make sure to escape it with a `\` beforehand.

The problem is my `explode()` function still attempts to split the escaped delimiters, so how do I tell it to ignore them?

Comment: This sounds like something can could be easily done if you use [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/fgetcsv) and [`fputcsv()`](http://php.net/fputcsv).

Comment: str_replace the \ and the delimeter befor you explode, and replace it back afterwards or take a look at the fgetcsv method.

Comment: have you considered [`serialize()`](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)ing the data for storage in the file? If you do this, PHP will handle this sort of problem for you...

Comment: What if the user inputs a string ending in a backslash?

Comment: @Sjoerd The first characters I escape are lone backslashes, that should solve that problem no?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use preg_split instead. By using a regex you can match a delimeter only if it is not preceded with a backslash.

Edit:

```
preg_split('~(?<!\\\)' . preg_quote($delimeter, '~') . '~', $text);
```

Comment: Do you have an example? I am not versed in regex. My delimiter is represented by `$this->_config->delimiter()`

Comment: And what would the pattern be? `[^\\\]\,` also eats up the last character before the delimiter

Comment: I've added an example with a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It influences the match, but does not use it when doing the splitting.

Comment: Great one, didn't know you could do that :) +1

Comment: I've typed `\\~`, but it thinks that `~` is preceded by backslash.

Comment: To allow escaping of the the backslash, so one can type `\\ ` and get `\ `, without the string being split, use this improvement to the regex: `/(?<![^\\]\\),/` (using `,` as delimiter)

Comment: This may work for this person's data but look-behind assertions will never be generally applicable to this issue until PCRE supports them having variable length (likely never). E.g.: `foo\\\\|bar` should split to "foo\\" and `bar` but the above solutions will fail. Case in point, the comment renderer here can't even deal with "foo\\" within \` marks

Answer (score 2):

None of the solutions here correctly handle any number of escape characters, or they leave them in the output. Here's an alternative:

```
function separate($string, $separator = '|', $escape = '\\') {
    if (strlen($separator) != 1 || strlen($escape) != 1) {
        trigger_error(__FUNCTION__ . ' requires delimiters to be single characters.', E_USER_WARNING);
        return;
    }
    $segments = [];
    $string = (string) $string;
    do {
        $segment = '';
        do {
            $segment_length = strcspn($string, "$separator$escape");
            if ($segment_length) {
                $segment .= substr($string, 0, $segment_length);
            }
            if (strlen($string) <= $segment_length) {
                $string = null;
                break;
            }
            if ($escaped = $string[$segment_length] == $escape) {
                $segment .= (string) substr($string, ++$segment_length, 1);
            }
            $string = (string) substr($string, ++$segment_length);
        } while ($escaped);
        $segments[] = $segment;
    } while ($string !== null);
    return $segments;
}
```

This will process a raw string like `foo\|ba\r\\|baz|` into `foo|bar\`, `baz`, and an empty string.

If you want to retain the escape character in the output, you will have to modify the function.

Note: this will have unpredictable behaviour if you're using [mb function overloading](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php).

Answer (score 0):

### Input Data

```
key1=val1;key2=val2start\;val2end;key3=val3\\;key4=val4\\\;key5=val5\\\\;key6=val6
```

### REGEX

```php
/(.*?[^\\](\\\\)*?);/
```

### Example

```
<?php

$data="key1=val1;key2=val2start\\;val2end;key3=val3\\\\;key4=val4\\\\\\;key5=val5\\\\\\\\;key6=val6";

$regex='/(.*?[^\\\\](\\\\\\\\)*?);/';
preg_match_all($regex, $data.';', $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
```

### Output

```php
Array
(
    [0] => key1=val1
    [1] => key2=val2start\;val2end
    [2] => key3=val3\\
    [3] => key4=val4\\\;key5=val5\\\\
    [4] => key6=val6
)
```

Comment: But why leave the escape characters in the string?

Comment: Fails on `$data="a;;b;;;c";`

Answer (score 0):

You will find this solution more useful than using regex for large strings. I employ a stream to allow usage of `fgetcsv`, which is optimized for this sort of thing.

```
<?php
function escaped_explode($string,$delimit,$escape=NULL,$enclosure=NULL,$max_line_length=0){
    $r=[];
    $stream = fopen('php://memory','r+');
    fwrite($stream, $string);
    rewind($stream);
    while (($data = fgetcsv($stream,$max_line_length,$delimit,$enclosure,$escape)) !== FALSE)
        $r=array_merge($r,$data);
    fclose($stream);
    return $r;
}
?>
```

Usage:

```
$pipelined_values = escaped_explode($source,'|','\\');
```

This is convenient also because you have the option of using enclosures, such as quotes, instead of only escape characters. This is nice if you run into parsing someone's blobs of JSON values, or other syntax, as you can both enclose and escape.

```
$source= <<<JSON
'{ "key":"val", "n":0}', 
'{ "key":"val", "n":1, "name": "French du\'Name" }',
'{ "key":"val", "n":2}'
JSON;
```

Can be interpreted

```
<?php
$objects=[];
$raw= escaped_explode($source, ',', '\\', "'");
foreach($raw as $r)
    $objects[] = json_decode($r);
?>
```