# How to split a string on comma that is NOT followed by a space?

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I want the results to be:

```
Cats, Felines & Cougars    
Dogs    
Snakes
```

This is the closest I can get.

```
$string = "Cats, Felines & Cougars,Dogs,Snakes";
$result = split(',[^ ]', $string);
print_r($result);
```

Which results in

```
Array
(
    [0] => Cats, Felines & Cougars
    [1] => ogs
    [2] => nakes
)
```

Comment: Use `\s` to match white spaces

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the split() function has been deprecated so I'm using preg_split instead.

Here's what you want:

```
$string = "Cats, Felines & Cougars,Dogs,Snakes";
$result = preg_split('/,(?! )/', $string);
print_r($result);
```

This uses ?! to signify that we want split on a comma only when not followed by the grouped sequence.

I linked the Perl documentation on the operator since preg_split uses Perl regular expressions:

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Look-Around-Assertions

Answer (score 6):

You can use a [negative lookahead](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html&ei=beihU53gM8ePuASVhoCgCg&usg=AFQjCNH50o6T1e3LK70EJqezzZTLsRPRhw&sig2=QANhqU9vpHESuhKW6_6rww&cad=rja) to achieve this:

```
,(?!\s)
```

In simple English, the above regex says match all commas *only* if it is not followed by a space (`\s`).

In PHP, you can use it with [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg_split), like so:

```
$string = "Cats, Felines & Cougars,Dogs,Snakes";
$result = preg_split('/,(?!\s)/', $string);
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Cats, Felines & Cougars
    [1] => Dogs
    [2] => Snakes
)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to split by a char, but want to ignore that char in case it is escaped, use a lookbehind assertion.

In this example a string will be split by ":" but "\:" will be ignored:

```
<?php
$string='a:b:c\:d';
$array=preg_split('#(?<!\\\)\:#',$string);
print_r($array);
?>
```

Results into:

Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c\:d
)

http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.preg-split.php

Comment: This is [the correct answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8519822/2943403) (not this question).