# Split text separated by comma into an array but ignore escaped delimiter \,

Tags: php, regex

The text is

```
a,b,c,d\,e,f,g
```

and I want to split these into an array based on delimiter `,` and ignore the escaped `,` like `\,e`

```
["a","b","c", "d,e", "f", "g"]
```

I've tried using explode like

```
explode(',', $data);
```

but it doesn't recognize the escaped `\` in the text.
How to split the text and ignore the escaped delimiter?

Comment: Can there be real backslashes in input such as: `a,b\\,c,d\,e,f,g` ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `preg_split` to split based on un-escaped commas (using a negative look-behind on the comma to check it is not preceded by a `\`), although you would need to post-process to remove the backslashes:

```
$string = 'a,b,c,d\,e,f,g';
$array = preg_split('/(?<!\\\\),/', $string);
$array = array_map(function ($v) { return str_replace('\\', '', $v); }, $array);
print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c [3] => d,e [4] => f [5] => g )
```

Comment: I'm on a cell phone, which is why you beat me by about 10 seconds :-)

Comment: Is that the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519793/php-explode-but-ignore-escaped-delimiter?

Comment: @NigelRen well spotted. Indeed it is, but my method of removing the backslashes is better than any proposed in those answers (at least, I think so). You could still close as a dupe - given that I answered before seeing the dupe I don't think I can ethically do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression for this, and they are quite good, but they are also quite hard to understand. Why not something more simplistic like:

```
$input  = "a,b,c,d\,e,f,g,h\,i\,j,k,l,m";
$output = [];
$buffer = "";

foreach (explode(",", $input) as $part) {
    if (substr($part, -1) == "\\") $buffer .= $part;
    else {
       $output[] = $buffer . $part;
       $buffer   = "";
    }
}

print_r($output);
```

This doesn't remove the backslashes, but it is now easy to add or remove that. This is the same algorithm that removes them:

```
foreach (explode(",", $input) as $part) {
    if (substr($part, -1) == "\\") $buffer .= substr($part, 0, -1) . ',';
    else {
       $output[] = $buffer . $part;
       $buffer   = "";
    }
}
```

I am aware that this is not a popular opinion, but changing something you can actually easy understand is a lot more fun than struggling to understand dense regular expressions. It's, of course, all quite subjective.

Comment: Well, is it subjective? I found an article on Hackernoon that puts it better into words than I ever could: [For the Love of Jeez, Stop Using Regex in Software](https://hackernoon.com/for-the-love-of-jeez-stop-using-regex-in-software-3a916e2c5987)

Answer (score 0):

Wihout regular expression

```
$ignore = '\\';
$arr = explode(',','a,b,c,d\,e,f,g');
array_walk($arr, function(&$v, $k) use ($ignore,&$arr){
  if(strpos($v, $ignore)){ 
   $v = str_replace($ignore, ',', $v).$arr[$k+1];
   unset($arr[$k+1]);
  }
 return $v;
});
```

Comment: what if `$ignore` is at the first offset?

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
$string = 'a,b,c,d\,e,f,g';
$str = str_replace("\,", '\\', $string);
$array = explode(',', $str);
print_r(str_replace('\\',',',$array));
```

result

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => d,e
    [4] => f
    [5] => g
)
```

Comment: Character substitution is an error-prone technique because it could possibly compromise legitimate data.