# How to split text based on two strings as one delimiter (for instance asterisks AND new line special character) using PHP?

Tags: php

Can you help me split a long text based on the **"AND"** logical expression, for a delimiter made of both six asterisks AND a new line special character?

I am new to PHP and doing my internship, and I have to fix a legacy issue.

The two delimiters are each special characters, requiring an escape function according to my basic knowledge.

**This is my data structure.** 

First chunk doesn't start with any delimiter.

******

Second chunk is separated from the first one by six asterisks plus a carriage return.

******

Third chunk is separated from the second one by six asterisks plus a carriage return.

******

And son on... and on.

******

But we might find other asterisks, maybe six like ****** inside the paragraph, and those one are not to be split.

Same for new lines without ****** which should stay the same.

******

Also note that the number of chunks is variable in my data source. And I know this is a problem with a stinky structure, but the benefit of storing combine chunks was studied, and chosen to save storing space and time. I heard that such a model sucks, but we need to deal with some legacy.

**This is what I would like to get, as a result.** 
Chunk 1:
First chunk doesn't start with any delimiter.

Chunk 2:
Second chunk is separated from the first one by six asterisks plus a carriage return.

Chunk 3:
Third chunk is separated from the second one by six asterisks plus a carriage return.

Chunk 4:
And son on... and on.

Chunk 5:
But we might find other asterisks, maybe six like ****** inside the paragraph, and those one are not to be split.

Same for new lines without ****** which should stay the same.

**This is the code I am using after adapting the explodeEscaped function found on the Internet.**

`print_r(explodeEscaped('***', $my_text_variable, '\n'));`

This function has been discussed on this platform, at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519793/php-explode-but-ignore-escaped-delimiter][1].

**This is the result I get from the code.**

First chunk doesn't start with any delimiter.

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519793/php-explode-but-ignore-escaped-delimiter) => [2] =>
Second chunk is separated from the first one by six asterisks plus a carriage return.

[3] => [4] =>
Third chunk is separated from the second one by six asterisks plus a carriage return.
[5] => [6] =>
And son on... and on.

[7] => [8] =>
But we might find other asterisks, maybe six like [9] => [10] => inside the paragraph, and those one are not to be split.

Same for new lines without [11] => [12] => which should stay the same.

[13] =>
Also note that the number of chunks is variable in my data source. And I know this is a problem with a stinky structure, but the benefit of storing combine chunks was studied, and chosen to save storing space and time.

Comment: How about `explode("******" . PHP_EOL, $my_text_variable)`?

Comment: This command is not creating separate chunks of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the algorithm, and succeeded to replace the delimiters at the beginning of the new lines, with the below code:

```
$pattern = '/^[\*]+/m';
preg_replace($pattern, '######', $text)); // Strip off the starting asterisks
```

That gives me a different problem, and I can split on the hash tags instead, since I don't have to escape them.

Answer (score 0):

```
  class testit(){

  public function __construct(){
   $str = "this is a string ****** some text to be removed /r/n";
   echo $this->delete_all_between("******", "/r/n", $str);
 // returns this is a string some text to be removed
  }
  private function delete_all_between($beginning, $end, $string) {
     $beginningPos = strpos($string, $beginning);
     $endPos = strpos($string, $end);
     if ($beginningPos === false || $endPos === false) {
        return $string;
     }

     $textToDelete = substr($string, $beginningPos, ($endPos + strlen($end)) - $beginningPos);

     return $this->delete_all_between($beginning, $end, str_replace($textToDelete, '', $string)); // recursion to ensure all occurrences are replaced
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To split your block of text by lines that are wholly comprised of six consecutive asterisks AND trim off any leading and trailing newline characters, I recommend the following pattern leveraging start of line and end of line anchors as well as the `\R` metacharacter to match newline sequences (`\n` or `\r\n`) that may surround the delimiting line.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/5UBOW))

```
$txt = <<<TXT
First chunk doesn't start with any delimiter.
******
Second chunk is separated from the first one by six asterisks plus a carriage return.
******
Third chunk is separated from the second one by six asterisks plus a carriage return.
******
And son on... and on.
******
But we might find other asterisks, maybe six like ****** inside the paragraph, and those one are not to be split.

Same for new lines without ****** which should stay the same.
TXT;

var_export(
    preg_split('/\R*^\*{6}$\R*/m', $txt, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'First chunk doesn\'t start with any delimiter.',
  1 => 'Second chunk is separated from the first one by six asterisks plus a carriage return.',
  2 => 'Third chunk is separated from the second one by six asterisks plus a carriage return.',
  3 => 'And son on... and on.',
  4 => 'But we might find other asterisks, maybe six like ****** inside the paragraph, and those one are not to be split.

Same for new lines without ****** which should stay the same.',
)
```

The `, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` parameters are not essential for the provided input string, but I find that including these flags makes the output more stable/reliable.